# doubt in arguments

Tags: xquery

I want to get only those elements in which number is greater than One. What should I use?Tokenizer is not working I guess here...

```
<games>  
    <game>  
        <Motion>False</Motion>  
        <Platform>Playstation3,XBox, typer</Platform>  
    </game>  
    <game>  
         <Motion>False</Motion>  
        <Platform>Playstation3</Platform>  
    </game>  
</games>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [contains()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-contains) function:

```
doc("games.xml")//game[contains(Platform, ",")]
```

**EDIT:** The query you posted does not match your XML markup. Try something like:

```
for $z in doc("videogames.xml")//game[contains(Platform, ",")]
return
<Platform>{$z/Motion}</Platform>
```

Comment: where do I put greater than Condition?

Comment: @user507087, sorry, I must have misunderstood. I thought you wanted the `<game>` elements with more than one platform, i.e. whose `<Platform>` elements contain a comma character. So what exactly do you want? :)

Comment: In my above input given in the question, when I run the query , I should get only the upper elements of game that has more than 1 platform- playstation3, Xbox, typer. It should discard the other one as numbr of platforms in that case is 1 only.

Comment: @user507087, so my solution should work, since it returns only the `<game>` elements whose `<Platforms>` elements contain a `,` character, which means more than one platform is present.

Comment: it is showing me nothing...no output is coming.I am returning game/<Motion....but nothing is coming out

Comment: @user507087, can you update your question with the exact code you're using?

Comment: cant we use some condition like greater than..?

Comment: shib.shilpa@gmail.com.....please send me ur email id..i will show you my data....

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get only those elements in
>   which number is greater than One. What
>   should I use?Tokenizer is not working
>   I guess here...

My guess is that you want only to work with games that are available for more than one platform.

**Use this test**:

```
/*/game[tokenize(Platform, ',')[2]]
```

**So, this simple XQuery**:

```
for $g in /*/game[tokenize(Platform, ',')[2]]
  return $g
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<games>   
  <game>   
    <Motion>False</Motion>   
    <Platform>Playstation3,XBox, typer</Platform>   
  </game>   
  <game>   
    <Motion>False</Motion>   
    <Platform>Playstation3</Platform>   
  </game>   
</games>
```

**returns**:

```
<game>   
    <Motion>False</Motion>   
    <Platform>Playstation3,XBox, typer</Platform>   
</game>
```